# how to group radio buttons

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

hey guys so i was wondering if its possible to group radio buttons. im not sure how to phrase this question.

okay take for example a table, that table has 4 columns: name, 1, 2 and 3; 1, 2, 3 being a rating. this table is for a user to rate chocolates like [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/RadioGrid/), now according to the demo one row one rating, one column one rating. now im thinking like what if a person wants to rate Twix and Snickers a 3? its not possible in that demo but is it possible to make it like that?

Comment: Works fine when i tried it on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kFCnC/

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain how it fails to meet your requirements. The page you link to has JavaScript code for preventing some combinations of choices. Just don’t use such code if you don’t want to impose such requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same 'name' attribute on each of the radio buttons that you're grouping. For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Snickers</td>
    <td>1<input type="radio" name="snickers" value="1"></td>
    <td>2<input type="radio" name="snickers" value="2"></td>
    <td>3<input type="radio" name="snickers" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See this [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/531461ee5c72b087c4df55aff5fe20e7)

Comment: You should probably put unique `value=""`s for each `input`, to help clarify what the difference is